# Can you return tags where condition is not met in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get `input` tags from a page, but I don't want to return any with the type attribute, `hidden`.

I can get all the `hidden` fields with `soup.find_all('input', attrs={'type': 'hidden'})` but you can't just negate that with `attrs!={'type': 'hidden'}`.

Is there a simple one-liner way of getting all tags which *don't* match a condition on a given attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to use a [function match](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function):

```
def input_not_type_hidden(tag):
    return tag.name == 'input' and tag.get('type') != 'hidden'

soup.find_all(input_not_type_hidden)
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about those. It needs `tag.name == 'input'`, not `tag.name = 'input'` though.